# module from node_modules directory checked into git not found but fixed by reinstalling

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, es6-modules

I'm using Node for the first time on a small script project, and I ran into a confusing situation I'm trying to understand.

Background: I created my project and set up my dependencies using `npm install --save <dep>` to add them to my `package.json`/`package-lock.json` files and save them to the `node_modules` directory in my project. I added `"type": "module"` to my `package.json` file to use ESM. Everything worked fine on my machine, and I committed my project to a git repo (including the contents of the `node_modules` directory).

However, when a colleague checked out the repo and tried to run my Node script they got a `ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND` error (see below) complaining that a file was not found, even though the file **was** present on disk (since the `node_modules` directory was checked into git).

Running `rm -r node_modules; npm install` fixed the error for them but didn't generate any diffs in git.

Why did this error occur and why was it fixed by re-running `npm install`? What's happening under the hood here, is there some global systemwide state that's being updated? What's the recommended way to check dependencies into git?

Here's the full error:

```
> $ node my-script.js
>
> node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:188
>   const resolvedOption = FSLegacyMainResolve(packageJsonUrlString, packageConfig.main, baseStringified);
>                          ^
> 
> Error: Cannot find package '/redacted/path/to/my/project/node_modules/chrome-launcher/package.json' imported from /redacted/path/to/my/project/my-script.js
>     at legacyMainResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:188:26)
>     at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:769:14)
>     at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:831:20)
>     at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1036:11)
>     at DefaultModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:251:12)
>     at DefaultModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:140:32)
>     at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:33)
>     at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36) {
>   code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
> }
> 
> Node.js v20.5.1
```

I expected the script to run successfully after being checked out on a new machine since the dependencies were all checked into git, but instead I had to run `rm -r node_modules; npm install`, which defeats the point of checking the dependencies into git. I want to check the dependencies into git to guard against the possibility of the packages disappearing from npm since I've heard that happens occasionally.